# "The same as..."

Tags: предлоги

How do I express "the same as..." in the following sentences in Russian?

1. "- Why did you learn French? - For the same reason you learned English."
2. "She's in the same university as me."

I'll give it a try anyway, as far as my knowledge of Russian grammar goes.

> Почему изучил ты французский? По той же причине, почему ты изучил английский.
>
> Она в том же университете, как я.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Почему ты выучил французский? По той же причине, *что* ты выучил английский.

(more formal: **по которой** instead of **что**)

Another possible (more colloquial) answer:

> **Потому же, почему** ты выучил английский.
>
> 2. Она учится/училась в том же университете, **что** и я.

Another version:

> Она учится *в одном со мной* университете.